# Cannot delete folders on windows

Tags: user-folders

I am using Windows 10 and am unable to delete some folders. I have tried restarting / refreshing but it doesnt work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How could you create those files in the first place? Windows don't allow backslash in file names.

Comment: i think they were created in linux when i lent the harddisk to a friend. so I should use linux to delete those folders ? Im not sure though. Its my only guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Windows to rename a file with a special character?](https://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a file that contains a backslash in the name under Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/409424/how-to-delete-a-file-that-contains-a-backslash-in-the-name-under-windows-7)

Comment: Not only are \ not allowed in a name, a file with . in front of the \ won't work either, because that would indicaute, current folder\... so it is missing the folder because of that. Yes a linux cd is needed here.

Comment: You might be able to remove the jaad folder using `rd /d jaad` from the commandline, to remove jaad and everything inside. Then recreate the folder jaad if you want to have that folder again.