# I accidentally changed my folder name to "D:". How can I rename it again?

Tags: windows-7

I have accidentally changed my folder name to "`D:`" and I don't know how. I have tried renaming it using command but no luck with simple `rename` command in Windows 7. Is there any way to change it?

EDIT: Attached image
[image]

Comment: would copying out the contents and simply deleting it be an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force Windows XP to rename a file with a special character?](http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-xp-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character), [How to delete (invalid) files with colon in their name under Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/165395/how-to-delete-invalid-files-with-colon-in-their-name-under-windows)

Comment: @DaveRook That one says it only applies to Services for UNIX (which was changed to Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications, and then deprecated as of Windows 8 and removed as of 8.1). I don't think it's applicable to normal Win32 usage, though it might still work. It's also needlessly complex and only really useful for continuous usage (their example was folders shared with *nix systems), rather than a one-off rename.

Comment: Fair comment Bob, removed it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The folder D: doesn't have any contents. I cannot even delete it.

Comment: To delete it, try using `del` in elevated command prompt

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of Bob yet? Removing the directory with `del "\\?\c:\temp\D:"` (after copying out the contents). `c:\temp\ ` being the complete path to that directory. Otherwise i'm afraid you'll need to use a live-linux cd to correct this problem.

Comment: Yeah, nothing worked on Windows. The only option left is to remove using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In explorer, select the folder and press F2. Then type in a new name and press enter.

If this doesn't work, copy the content of the folder to a new folder, and delete the old folder.

Comment: Neither of them works. Can you verify it before posting as an answer?

Comment: I can't because normally you cannot make a folder named D:. Unless you can provide me with instructions on making such (but you said it was made by accident) I cannot confirm this, although normally it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Linux live cd to delete folder. you can use [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), [Kali linux](http://www.kali.org/) etc. any of your choice.