# Delete a file that could not be found by CMD

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

(My problem is in Windows XP, but i suppose it could be extended to other Windows OSes as well.)

I am trying to delete a file named "Σâ└í", which could not be deleted even by the "del" command in CMD, with the reason that "the file could not be found." However, the command:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn
```

does display the file in that folder contents list. Also, i am unable to delete its parent folder with a "rd" command, with the reason being "the directory is not empty". This file occupies 1.87 GB on the drive, so no question of it not existing. There is another file named "low" in the same folder, which is shown to occupy 0 KB on the disk. Both the files seem to have no extensions. I also tried the "Unlocker" program, the CMD steps in Safe Mode, none of which worked.

What should I do to delete this stubborn file?

Comment: For removing the parent folder, did you use the "Subfolders" switch (`rd /s`)?

Comment: Also, have you tried the methods offered in this other SU question yet? [How to delete (invalid) files with colon in their name under Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/165395/how-to-delete-invalid-files-with-colon-in-their-name-under-windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, i just tried both the methods mentioned by you above, it still doesn't work! In both cases, it says the file could not be found!

Comment: Have you run a chkdsk recently? Strangely named files consuming large amounts of disk space that don't delete properly is a symptom of data corruption.

Comment: Is the file hidden or marked 'read only'? What do you see in the 1st 2 lines resulting from `dir /r`?

Answer (score 0):

Boot off a USB drive with Linux installed on it. Then find the file and delete it by either searching for it in the file Explorer or opening the terminal and type

> rm -i {filename}

The terminal will delete the file and ask conformation before you delete it. **If the i isn't lowercase, it will not ask for conformation before the deletion. **[Click this link if you need more help with the terminal](http://sourcedigit.com/3159-delete-files-linux-ubuntu-using-rm-terminal-command/) *****
[Click this link to learn how to install Linux on a USB drive](http://instructables.com/id/How-to-Install-a-Linux-OS-in-your-USB-Flash-Drive-/step2/Downloading-the-Ubuntu-OS-and-the-USB-Installer/)